# Mirage OS and Xen - Storing data on a DB

Tags: xen, mirage, unikernel

Which are the best options available if I want my MirageOS unikernel to store some information on an external DB (doesn't matter the type)? I had a look at different solutions but it seems that none of the libraries offering DB bindings are XEN-compatible. Last one I tried is Redis but apparently the ocaml library cannot be compiled for XEN.

Answer (score 2):

The Redis code looks like it should work on Xen. It appears (from a quick look) that there is a `Redis` core module and a separate `Redis_lwt` that applies it to `Lwt_unix`. You probably need to write a Mirage-equivalent version of this:

https://github.com/0xffea/ocaml-redis/blob/master/src/redis_lwt.ml

Most bits would be the same, but things using Unix APIs would need changing. E.g the `Lwt_unix.socket` would need changing to using Mirage's TCP/IP API.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Anyway do you know if there are any other MirageOS/XEN-ready DB libraries?

Comment: Curious about this, did you end up actually getting that to work ? Taking a look at the code, it seems there are references to unix stuff in more than redis_lwt.ml unfortunatly, at least now